# Migrating setting: in context.xml from Tomcat9 to Wildfly 14.0.1Final

Tags: tomcat, wildfly

How could I move some configuration from Tomcat application server's context.xml to Wildfly? I really need the datas from the Environment element.

The context.xml contains something like this:

```
<Context>

    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/tomcat-web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>


    <Environment name="some.very.important.config.path" value="C:\path\to\the\config\folder"

         type="java.lang.String" />


</Context>
```

How could I make this in Wildfly application server?

**Update:**

I have to use JNDI (for now) because it is an app is written by someone else.

The code to reach the injectable config path looks something like this.

```
        env = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
        configPath = (String) env.lookup("some.very.important.config.path");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>`
  WildFly watches for changes in this file by default
- `<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/tomcat-web.xml</WatchedResource>`
  Not relevant in WildFly. The `WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml` file is used for similar purposes and is also watched by default
- `<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>`
  Not relevant in WildFly
- `<Environment name="some.very.important.config.path" value="C:\path\to\the\config\folder" type="java.lang.String" />`
  Compose a text file named (for example) `configure-wildfly.cli` with the following content

  ```
  # Execute offline
  embed-server --server-config=standalone.xml

  # Add system properties
  /system-property=some.very.important.config.path:add(value=C:\path\to\the\config\folder)
  /system-property=some.other.important.config.value:add(value=foobar)

  # Bind an entry into the naming service
  /subsystem=naming/binding=java\:global\/config\/important\/path:add(binding-type=simple, type=java.lang.String, value="C:\path\to\the\config\folder")

  stop-embedded-server
  ```

  and then run it with:

  ```
  ${WILDFLY_HOME}/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=configure-wildfly.cli
  ```

  Scripting it like this makes it easy to reconstruct your server from it's base setup. You could source control this file if you want.

Access the system properties:

```
 String configPath = System.getProperty("some.very.important.config.path");
```

Lookup the value in JNDI:

```
 Context ctx = new InitialContext();
 String configPath = (String)ctx.lookup("java:global/config/important/path");
```

or inject it

```
 @Resource(lookup="java:global/config/important/path")
 private String configPath;
```

Comment: Thank you! The web-app still does not run, probably for some other reason, but I gave you +1 because the property is present in standalone.xml as system property. However I am not sure whether I can reference them with JNDI as `env = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");`

Comment: These are system properties. Use [java.lang.System.getProperty("some.very.important.config.path")](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-) to access them. Or do you want to use JNDI? We can do a similar thing to put these values into the Naming service if you want.

Comment: Could you please show me how to put these properties to the Naming service correctly? I've been trying based on Wildfly documentation but I am unsure about it being correct or not.